# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_navigator.dispatch') on navigating to screen in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to navigate to a certain screen when clicking on notification but I get above mentioned error. I have read oter questions and tried to solve it but I couldn't find solution for my problem.

here is my **MainApp.js**

```
import {NavigationContainer, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {NavStack} from './src/RootNavigator/StackNavigation';
import {NavStack2} from './src/RootNavigator/MainNavigator';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
} from './src/RootNavigator/MainNavigator/NavigationService';
import {dispatchFunc, saveToken, checkPopUps} from './src/Redux/action';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import Strings from './src/Translation';
import NavigationService from './src/RootNavigator/MainNavigator/NavigationService';
import {navigationRef} from './RootNavigation';

export default function App(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const login = useSelector(state => state.user.login);
  const language = useSelector(state => state.user.language);
  const [isAnimate, setAnimate] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(
      async remoteMessage => {
        console.log(
          'A new FCM message arrived!',
          JSON.stringify(remoteMessage),
        );
      },
    );
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
  const updateData = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      getFcmToken();
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
    messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('remoteMessage', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Message handled in the background!',
        JSON.stringify(remoteMessage),
      );
    });
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        JSON.stringify(remoteMessage),
      );
      // Alert.alert('ap[iii', 'lolll');
      Alert.alert('Alert Title', 'My Alert Msg');
       NavigationService.navigate('MyBooking');
    });
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.data,
          );
        }
      });
  };
  const getFcmToken = async () => {
    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
      console.log('Your Firebase Token is:', fcmToken);
      dispatch(saveToken(fcmToken));
    } else {
      console.log('Failed', 'No token received');
    }
  };
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <PopUpBox okClick={() => dispatch(dispatchFunc())} />
      {!login ? <NavStack /> : <NavStack2 />}
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import MAINAPP from "./MainApp";
import { Store, persistor } from "./src/Redux/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import RemotePushController from  './src/Service/RemotePushController'

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => SplashScreen.hide() , 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Provider store={Store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <MAINAPP />
            <RemotePushController />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**RootNavigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

const navigate = (name, params) =>
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);

export default {
  navigate,
};
```

**NavigationService.js**

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
let _navigator;
function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}
function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    }),
  );
}
export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

And if i update **MainApp.js** like this, then i get this error:

> ```
> The action 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' was not handled by any navigator.
> ```

```
<NavigationContainer
      ref={navigatorRef => {
        NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
      }}>
      <PopUpBox okClick={() => dispatch(dispatchFunc())} />
      {!login ? (
        <NavStack
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <NavStack2
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      )}
..... remaining code as it is....
```

Comment: It is possible that navigator might not have finished mounting or might not be ready when trying to navigate. Check if navigator is ready as described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop#handling-initialization)

Comment: what to do of its not ready? navigation is working now if app is in foregraoud or backgroud but if its quit, it says navigaion is not ready